# Facebook Python API friends paging next returns empty array

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was just messing up with the Facebook python API.

I was trying to list all of my friends.

Here's the code :

```
friends = graph.get_connections("me","friends")

while(friends['data']):
   for friend in friends['data']:
        allfriends.append(friend['name'])
   try:
        friends=requests.get(friends['paging']['next']).json()
   except KeyError:
       print "Key Error"

print allfriends
```

This code just lists couple of my friends. When I try to make a request to the url in [paging][next], it simply returns an empty array.

I am unable to understand, as to where am I going wrong? The next url should retrieve the next set of names from the friendlist I belive.

Kindly help.

Thank You

Comment: If there are more friends then it should return more yes. My guess is that you are using API v2.0 or later which means you will only get friends that have granted user_friends permission to the app and not all your friends

Comment: So other friends have to grant permission, for me to simply list them?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I would suggest that you read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: Oh thanks. I was unaware of that.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the following:

```
friends = graph.get_connections("me","friends")

while(friends['data']):
    try:
        for friend in friends['data']:
            allfriends.append(friend['name'])
        friends=requests.get(friends['paging']['next']).json()
    except KeyError:
       print "Key Error"
print allfriends
```

This is a better way of getting the correct data through Facebook Graph.

Comment: `print "Key Error"` won't stop the while loop. Use the `break` statement instead will help

Answer (score 0):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me/friends
```

The above url will only **only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.**
[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends)